# Additivity of expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say I have a set $\Omega$ with a probability $P$ on its subsets (the fact that it could be undefined on some subset is not important here, let's not think about that). I have a random variable $(X,Y): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, I define the probability induced by the random variable as $P_{X,Y}(A)=P((X,Y)^{-1}(A))$, with $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. A well known result tells me that (given $\omega=(x,y) \in \Omega$): $$\int_{\Omega} \phi((X,Y)(\omega))dP=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi(x) dP_{X,Y}$$

Consequently, taking $\phi =x+y$, I have that $E[(X,Y)]= \int_{\Omega} (X,Y)(\omega) dP=\sum_{x_j,y_i \in \Omega} (X,Y)(x_i,y_j) p_{x,y}(x_i,y_j)$ if $\Omega$ is countable, where $p_{x,y}$ is the probability that $(X,Y)(\omega)=(x_i,y_j)$.

What I don't get is why it is that $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are integrable. For instance, if I had a random variable $X+Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ that assume all positive integer values, I don't get why $$E[X+Y]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n p_{x,y}(\{X+Y=n\})=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i p_x(\{X=i\}) + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} j p_y (\{Y=j\})=E[X]+E[Y]$$

The integral interpretation, also, doesn't help me in figuring this out. I wonder, also, if there is a criterion such that we know when integrating $\phi$ is additive with respect to the random variables. For instance, the expected value is found taking $\phi=x+y$, and we have additivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n}n\mathsf{P}\left(X+Y=n\right)=\sum_{n}\sum_{i+j=n}\left(i+j\right)\mathsf{P}\left(X=i\wedge Y=j\right)=$$$$\sum i\sum_{j}\mathsf{P}\left(X=i\wedge Y=j\right)+\sum j\sum_{i}\mathsf{P}\left(X=i\wedge Y=j\right)=$$$$\sum i\mathsf{P}\left(X=i\right)+\sum j\mathsf{P}\left(Y=j\right)$$

Comment: Yeah thanks, I have tried doing this way and it turns out to work. The key to work this out (both with the integral and with the series) seems to be the fact that you can separate the two variables, and using in a clever way the fact that $P_{X,Y}(x_i,y_j)=P(X=x_i \wedge Y=y_j)$

Comment: Actually in order to prove that expectation is linear you can just use the more basic: $\mathbb{E}\left(X+Y\right):=\int X\left(\omega\right)+Y\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)=\int X\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)+\int Y\left(\omega\right)\mathsf{P}\left(d\omega\right)=\mathbb{E}X+\mathbb{E}Y$. That is also more general (the rv's do not have to be discrete).

Comment: You are absolutely right, don't know why I wanted to mess things up. It was a good exercise anyway. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you have written is not correct. $\phi$ is a function of two variables and you should write $\int \phi (x,y)\, dP_{X,Y}$ on the right side.  $\phi=1$ doesn't give you anything. It gives you $1=1$!. For $E(X+Y)=EX+EY$ take $\phi (x,y)=x+y$ and use the fact that marginals of $P_{X,Y}$ are $P_X$ and $P_Y$.

Comment: Yeah, of course $\phi$ is what you said, thanks

Comment: Also, what do you mean by marginals? I was trying to rearrange the series or integrate in some useful way, but maybe tou are talking about something different? (Or maybe it’s just me who isn’t aware of the term “marginal of $P_{x,y}$)

Comment: If $\phi$ depends only on $x$ then $\int \phi (x,y) \, dP_{X,Y}= \int \phi (x,y) \, dP_X$  and similarly when  $\phi$ depends only on $y$. $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are the marginal distributions and $P_{X,Y}$ is the joint distribution.

Comment: Sorry for bad typo, don't have space. Hope I got it now. For the integral,  $\int_{R^2}(x+y)dP_{X,Y}= \int_R x dP_{X,Y} + \int_R y dP_{X,Y}$, and in the first integral $dP_{X,Y}=dP_{X}$ cause for every subset $A$ of $R^2$, x^{-1} (A)= B \times R$ with $B \in \Omega$because y isn't involved, and the integral can thus be simplified in terms of the x only. For the series, maybe if I rearrange it this way, it works: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x+y)p(n)=\sum_{n}\sum_{i+j=n} (i+j)p(X=i,Y=j)$ and rearranging $\sum_{i}i \sum_{j} p(X=i,Y=j) + \sum_{j} j \sum_{i}p(X=i,Y=j)=\sum_i i P(X=i) + \sum_{j} j P(Y=j)$

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Ok, I just noticed the comment above is messed up, but it doesn't allow me to edit it. anyone knows what to do?